# Shift identification and correction in time series with seasonal variation

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I am working on an environmental time series characterized by seasonal variations, in this case, nutrient concentrations. Due to changes in methodologies, the baseline has shifted at some period leading to "shifts" (highlighted in red on the plots). There is no external evidence for the baseline shifts. However, the shifted portions of the times series correspond to a specific period of analysis, meaning that these shifts are for sure due to technical bias (the calibration solution for example) and not biological variations.

[image]

My question is: what is the most correct way to test whether these shifts need to be corrected? Do they statistically affect the time-series variation? I thought about calculating the trend with and without the shift and see whether the slopes of the trends are statistically different? Or calculate the average annual variation and the 95 quantiles without the shifted period and see whether the shift is comprised within the 95 confidence interval? Or simply calculate the mean of the shift and the mean over the rest of the series (on the same periods to avoid seasonal bias) and test for any significant difference? I understand that the way of testing should depend on the use being made of the series but I would like to "clean" the series and ultimately store both a raw and "corrected" version in the database.

Comment: What is the evidence for the baseline shift? External or only these data?

Comment: There is no external evidence for the baseline shifts. However, the shifted portions of the times series correspond to a specific period of analysis, meaning that these shifts are for sure due to technical bias (the calibration solution for example) and not biological variations. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add this new information to the post as an edit? Not everybody reads comments! (I have no idea myself for an answer, sorry)